# В каком виде подавать запросы в БД sqlite3 на python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, sqlite

Есть класс по работе с БД

```
class Sql:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connect = sqlite3.connect('ranobes.db')
        self.cursor = self.connect.cursor()

    def get_where_stopped_by_name(self, name):
        with self.connect:
            return self.cursor.execute(f"SELECT where_stopped FROM main WHERE ranobe_name = ?", (name,)).fetchall()

    def add_new_ranobe(self, name, where_stopped, comment=None):
        if comment is None:
            with self.connect:
                return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO main (ranobe_name,where_stopped) VALUES (?,?)", (name,where_stopped))
        else:
            with self.connect:
                return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO main (ranobe_name,where_stopped,comment) VALUES (?,?,?)", (name, where_stopped, comment))
```

Когда в бд записываешь новую строку, то в там она отображается в виде обычной строки [image: введите сюда описание изображения], но вот если пытаешься что-то достать, то информация представляется в таком формате `('Overlord',)`, то есть в виде кортежа.

Соответственно, чтобы представить это дело в читабельном для пользователя формате применяю костыль

```
def sql_to_str(sql):
    return str(sql).replace("(","").replace(",)","")
```

А можно как то без костыля?

Comment: Что мешает просто достать объект из кортежа? `.fetchall()[0][0]` или типа того

Comment: @andreymal Я пробовал пробегаться по всем элементам кортежа и получал `('Overlord',)` как элемент, сейчас попробовал как вы показали и получилось. Я не понимаю, кортеж что ли рассматривается как двумерный объект?

Comment: fetchall возвращает не просто кортеж, а список кортежей. Когда возвращается одна строка из таблицы, получается список, внутри которого один кортеж, и уже внутри этого кортежа лежит одна строка. Количество кортежей в списке соответствует числу полученных строк, а количество объектов в кортеже — запрошенным столбцам

Comment: Для того, что бы проще понять, почему именно так, запомните простую мысль - коннектор всегда возвращает набор записей - таблицу, в которой может быть несколько строк и несколько столбцов. Когда вы запрашиваете одно значение, то получаете таблицу из одной строки и одного столбца.

Comment: Еще одним вариантов решения может быть использование ORM - объектных моделей-оберток. Один из самых простых для освоения - ponyORM